# Receiving mails via mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun

I have a server on which i use mailgun for sending mails, which works fine, DNS records are added fine account is setup with mailgun fine too.

I cant receive inbound mails with it for some reason, i have a route made on mailgun so it can forward the mail where i want. catch_all(), forward("http://app.theautominer.com/inbox/mailgun")

Exactly what i need is when i send mail to someone via mailgun and if he replies i want this route to catch the reply mail and forward it to my server and store to DB.

How can i do this? Should i somehow add mailgun mails or smth?

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your domain's  mx records to mailgun mx servers. Login mailgun panel > domains > click on domain > Domain Verification & DNS > see the MX records. And set them into the domain's DNS settings panel. You can get all sent mail to your domain.